# Header redirect workaround: headers already sent

Tags: php, server, http-headers

I know in principle the common reasons for header redirects failing. I have code that worked 100% perfectly on my old server. No errors, correct functionality, and redirected when required. Now that I have moved to a new server a nasty little catch has arisen.

I have php code for some preliminary stuff, including multiple files at the top of the program,

```
include_once("include/stuff/usefulstuff.php");
```

one of which starts sessions (one of those typical go-tos for header problems). After this the header call normally occurs.

Now virtually all of this can be shifted to below the header call except for one very important piece of code. One of the required pieces of code is the database connection. It is information returned from the database which determines whether the header call should happen in the first place.

```
   require_once("databaseconnection.php");
   require_once("include/getuser.php");
   $checkUserID = getuser($user_id, $dbh);

   if ((!isset($_GET['id']))&&($checkUserID!=null)){
       //flush();
       header("Location: ./login.php"); /* Redirect browser */
       $dbh=null;
       exit();
}
```

With everything other than this requisite code placed below the header call, the resulting error message complains saying specifically that the headers have already been sent by databaseconnection.php.

Why might this be happening on this new server, and what might be the most... elegant... way of going about fixing it (other than copy-pasting all the code from databaseconnection.php and getuser.php into the main file)?

Edit: the redirect happens correctly when the contents of databaseconnection.php (which is UTF-8 without BOM) are copy-pasted directly into the main file. I don't understand this, the database connection doesn't output anything, and other include methods do not seem to trigger the header failure.

Comment: You moved servers, database connection file produces output, server complains about headers being sent - what I can conclude out of this is that your new server can't connect to the db, yields an error of some sort and that's where problems start.

Comment: Have you checked if there maybe is a BOM in your databaseconnection.php?

Comment: @N.B. Nope. Other pages connect no problem with the db.

Comment: @Philipp    BOM? comments must be at least 15 characters in length

Comment: byte order mark. If you nailed down that databaseconnection.php is the problem, focus on it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark, sry :p I think you can use this http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/ to check for it

Comment: @Philipp thanks: gave that a check and it reports that the html tag has no language attribute (which is a curious thing to say when there's no html in the file) and that "Encoding declared only in HTTP header", although I'm not certain what implications that has.

Comment: @sidyll I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that it was the use of something like include/require/include_once etc. that was the cause of the problem?

Comment: What does it say for "Byte order mark (BOM)" under "Character encoding"

Comment: @Philipp Oh sorry, it says "No"

Comment: Note: the redirect happens correctly when the contents of databaseconnection.php are copy-pasted directly into the main file

Comment: That means it's something with the file itself. Check its contents with a hex editor and compare the beginning of database connection file with other files that work. Also, ensure you don't have closing php tag `?>` since it's not needed and people usually leave a space / newline character after it which causes the error mentioned.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks. closing '?>' it was! Crazy, crazy stuff.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your site.